# Como reemplazar el texto seleccionado por un <Chip> en un autocomplete mui

Tags: autocompletar, mui, nextjs13

espero puedan ayudarme, tengo un Autocomplete que me funciona bien, cuando busco la data me trae lo que necesito y me lo carga a mi TextField que tengo en mi Autocomplete, lo que quiero es que cuando le de Click al dato seleccionado en vez de que me lo cargue en un texto quiero que solo se vea en un componente Chip de Mui, actualmente lo conseguí se me muestra la informacion en un Chip pero tambien en texto y se duplica, este es mi Autocomplete:

```
<Autocomplete
    fullWidth
    options={searchResults}
    noOptionsText='Sin opciones'
    getOptionLabel={(option: any) => option.formatted_address}
    isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.place_id === value.place_id}
    onInputChange={(event, value) => setInputValue(value)}
    onChange={(event, item) => {
      setSelectedOption(item); // Almacena la opción seleccionada en el estado local
      onChange(item); // Actualiza el valor del control con el texto de la opción seleccionada
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
      {...params}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position='start'>
            <LocationOnIcon sx={{ color: '#1B3665' }} />
          </InputAdornment>
        ),
        endAdornment: selectedOption ? (
          <Chip label={selectedOption.formatted_address} onDelete={() => setSelectedOption(null)} />
        ) : null,
      }}
    />
    )}
  />
```

mencionar que este Autocomplete **no es múltiple**, solo quiero que se vea el dato seleccionado, pero quiero que se muestre en un .

actualmente este es mi resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden apreciar, se ve duplicado... quiero mostrar el dato seleccionado solo en el Chip de Mui.

Les agradezco su respuesta, saludos.